# Missing Outputs from Three-Way ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to do a 3-way ANOVA using this code:

```
ANOVA <- aov(df$GSI ~ df$Area * df$Site * df$Gear, data = df)
summary(ANOVA)
```

But the summary output only gives me these rows:

```
df$Area
df$Site
df$Gear
df$Area:df$Gear
df$Site:df$Gear
Residuals
```

It is missing the rows for `df$Area:df$Site` and `df$Area:df$Site:df$Gear`. I have also tried writing out the code like this:

```
ANOVA <- aov(df$GSI ~ df$Area + df$Site + df$Gear + 
           df$Area:df$Site + df$Area:df$Gear + df$Site:df$Gear +
           df$Area:df$Site:df$Gear, data = df)
```

And it gives me the same result. Why are some results missing from my ANOVA summary?

Comment: We need to see your data to be sure, but most likely you don't have enough independent data to estimate all these effects.

Comment: I realized after looking at the raw data that the Site variable is a subcategory of Area. Would that be the problem, since they are not independent of each other?  That's the specific interaction that isn't showing up too. So maybe what I need is to just do a two-way anova?

Comment: That is most likely the case here. I couldn't really answer about the two-way. I have not seen any data, any design, or any information about the varibales you are looking at.

Comment: Well I appreciate you giving what input you can but there's only so much information about unpublished private data that I'm legally allowed to post on the internet..

Comment: why not change category names, substitute text strings, randomize numbers?